# Joomla 1.7:- How do i do this please (kinda facebook)

Tags: joomla

Joomla comes out standard with registered user, and public user

If I add a third (registered) User that allows the third user to a) create a single separate page in Joomla that the user can input pictures (like you do on face book). b) Access all pages as the standard registered user does.

How do I go about that in Joomla 1.7, add a third (registered) User and give it level 2 accesses?
Then how I create a single page for each user. Somehow I need a reference to each user’s page and show that in a list and control the list search parameters.  And i need the page viewable when selected and in the page info needs to be received by the third user. I’m not creating face book but I need that sort of techno somehow.
Can someone point me to what I need to look at, editorials, videos, etc. I know I need to lean PHP better.

Could I make a foulder for each registered user to hold photo's and name the folder acourding to the user's name or email address.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to go with a component that offers the functionality that you need. You will find it easier to control the user rights there as they are standard settings available. This is more convenient than building everything from scratch.

Some well known components are:

- [Community Builder](http://www.joomlapolis.com/community-builder) (main component free)
- [JomSocial](http://www.jomsocial.com/) (commercial component)

There are more components and plugins available, you may also want to search the Joomla Extensions Directory (JED) for something suitable (http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/social-web)